# Load data incrementally from an on-premise Oracle database

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to load data incrementally from an on-premise Oracle database.

I know that inside ADF I can create a self-hosted integration run-time, a linked service by the specific Oracle connector, the related dataset and a pipeline with a copy activity, but I don't know how detecting data changes, perhaps using an Oracle tool.

Any suggests to me, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change Data Capture (CDC) resources in ADF does not support Oracle dataset. Below are the only supported datasets in ADF for CDC.

[image]
**Img reference:** [Change Data Capture Resource - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-change-data-capture-resource#supported-data-sources).

Therefore, the recommended solution to track the changes in the source data and incrementally load the data from oracle database to sink would be using the watermark column. Watermark column could be the timestamps or increasing unique identifier.

- Create the watermark table with the initial value of the table as `1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`

[image: img]

- Take the lookup activity1 in the ADF and create the source dataset for  `watermark table`.
  Query in Lookup activity 1: `select <watermark_Column> from <watermark_table>.`
- Take the lookup activity2 and get the maximum watermark value from the source table.
  Query in Lookup2: `select max(<created_date>) as max_created_date from <src-table-name>`
- Take the copy activity and connect  it with lookup1 and 2 in such a way to be executed only after lookup1 and lookup2 got executed. Take the oracle dataset as source and give the query as,

```
select distinct id from <src-table-name> where <created_date> 
> '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.<watermark_column>} and <created_date> <= '@{activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.max_created_date}'
```

Replace `<src-table-name>` with the source table name, `<created_date>` with the watermark column in source table used for tracking changes, `<watermark_column>` with the column name in watermark table.

- Take the sink dataset in copy activity.
- Update the watermark table with the maximum value of watermark column from the target table using lookup activity.

```sql
update watermark_table
set watermark_column='@{activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.max_created_date}';
```

Reference: [Incrementally copy data from a source data store to a destination data store - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview)