# Azure Data Factory - Oracle and SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Request some pointers.

I am new to Azure and have worked using AWS previously. Have used DMS and some lambdas as part of migrating data from Oracle and SQL server external data into cloud (s3). Similarly in Azure what would be the services that can pull data from Oracle and SQL server (along with CDC) into Azure blob storage? I don't want to do any transformations for now and need to just pull the initial and changed data regularly and store for further processing.

I was going through ADF and the Oracle/SQL connectors. Does ADF help bringing the oracle and sql server's data (with full initial load and CDC data) into azure blob storage and serve the purpose of bringing batch and near real time CDC data?

TIA.

Comment: What type of SQL servers are you using? Is it Azure or On-prem?

Comment: On prem oracle and sql servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [Doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/106348),

> Currently, ADF does not support **Change Data capture** for On-premises databases because they require Self-hosted integrations runtimes. CDC only supports Azure Integration runtimes.

If you want to use ADF for this, **your database tables require Watermark column** which should have the timestamps. Also, you need a table `temp` containing an old timestamp value.

Get the maximum date of the watermark column from the source table using lookup activity. Also, use another lookup activity to get the timestamp value from the given `temp` table.

After these, you need to check for the new data by checking with the timestamp in this table using copy activity.

After copy activity, update the timestamp of `temp` table with the maximum date that you got from lookup using **Script activity**.

On every pipeline run, the maximum date from source table will be selected from first lookup and timestamp from `temp` table will be selected from second lookup. The copy activity will copy only the new data to the target and the maximum date will be updated in the `temp` table so that on next pipeline run the new data will be selected.

Check this similar [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76124439/load-data-incrementally-from-an-on-premise-oracle-database/76155100#76155100) for reference by @**Aswin**.